# HTTP Bad Request - Browser Hook

Tags: browser, http-headers

I am hooking firefox's send and WSARecv. Send should remove the gzip header (=> Accept-Encoding: none) and WSARecv hook shall edit the data.

At the moment the WSARecv function doesn't change any data, but only prints it out for the debug log. Many sites work, but sometimes images do not get loaded or the page doesn't.

I could find the following server response (Error 400 Bad Request) in bing.com's answer in the WSARecv function:

`Hooked Send 
GET /fd/ls/l?IG=c5c4c27da26c4c5db3e1ed6adbfafc0d&TYPE=Event.ClientInst&DATA=%5B%7B%22T%22:%22CI.Init%22,%22FID%22:%22CI%22,%22Name%22:%22Base%22,%22TS%22:1253465714457%7D,%7B%22W%22%3A1670%2C%22H%22%3A701%2C%22T%22:%22CI.Dims%22,%22FID%22:%22HP%22,%22Name%22:%22br%22,%22TS%22:1253465714457%7D,%7B%22Data%22%3A-1%2C%22T%22:%22CI.Test%22,%22FID%22:%22HP%22,%22Name%22:%22IsLive%22,%22TS%22:1253465714457%7D,%7B%22Time%22%3A489%2C%22T%22:%22CI.Load%22,%22FID%22:%22HP%22,%22Name%22:%22bg%22,%22TS%22:1253465714946%7D%5D HTTP/1.1

00001138 3.75038576 [4024] Host: a4.bing.com

00001139 3.75038576 [4024] User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 YFF35 Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)

00001140 3.75038576 [4024] Accept: image/png,image/;q=0.8,/;q=0.5

00001141 3.75038576 [4024] Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

00001142 3.75038576 [4024] Accept-Encoding: none

00001143 3.75038576 [4024] Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,;q=0.7

00001144 3.75038576 [4024] Keep-Alive: 300

00001145 3.75038576 [4024] Connection: keep-alive

00001146 3.75038576 [4024] Referer: http://www.bing.com/

00001147 3.75038576 [4024] Cookie: MUID=D22A51BCBBD54DD3BE74682327101C0A; SRCHD=MS=904338&D=792606&AF=IE8SRC; SRCHUSR=AUTOREDIR=0&GEOVAR=&DOB=20090704; SRCHUID=V=2&GUID=2069ECD3092B453ABFCB9C4762409ACD; _HOP=; _FS=mkt=de-DE&ui=de-DE

(end of header)`

Hooked WSARecv
00001152 4.03753757 [4024] HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
00001153 4.03753757 [4024] Cache-Control: private
00001154 4.03753757 [4024] Content-Length: 0
00001155 4.03753757 [4024] P3P: CP="NON UNI COM NAV STA LOC CURa DEVa PSAa PSDa OUR IND", policyref="http://privacy.msn.com/w3c/p3p.xml"
00001156 4.03753757 [4024] Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2009 16:55:17 GMT
00001157 4.03753757 [4024] Connection: keep-alive
00001158 4.03753757 [4024]
00001159 4.03753757 [4024] HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
00001160 4.03753757 [4024] Server: AkamaiGHost
00001161 4.03753757 [4024] Mime-Version: 1.0
00001162 4.03753757 [4024] Content-Type: text/html
00001163 4.03753757 [4024] Content-Length: 216
00001164 4.03753757 [4024] Expires: Sun, 20 Sep 2009 16:55:17 GMT
00001165 4.03753757 [4024] Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2009 16:55:17 GMT
00001166 4.03753757 [4024] Connection: close
00001167 4.03753757 [4024]
00001168 4.03753757 [4024]  
00001169 4.03753757 [4024] Bad Request 
00001170 4.03753757 [4024]  
00001171 4.03753757 [4024]

## Bad Request

00001172 4.03753757 [4024] Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

00001173 4.03753757 [4024] Reference #7.cea432c3.1253465717.0 
00001174 4.03753757 [4024]  
00001175 4.03753757 [4024]

My question is: What is wrong with my HTTP headers? Why do some pages come up with a 400 error. Is it the Accept-Encoding:none?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"none" is not an acceptable value for the "Accept-Encoding" header.  Not all servers look at that header, but those that do will usually validate it before using it.  To make the server send uncompressed data, omit the header altogether, or set it to "identity" instead.